# call External webservice using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I developed asp.net WCF service.I have hosted it in another system.now i need to get the WCF webservice to my System using JQUERY Function.my problem is I dnt knw how to call that webservice hosted in another system.How to call external webservice from jquery?

Comment: google it! :http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `AJAX` jQuery method:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:4305/Service/YourService',
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data) {
     alert('WCF service called');
  }
});
```

There is also an article on Code Project to achieve this with WCF.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue regarding cross domain scripting?  Try JSONP.  This will allow you to call a webservice hosted on a system w/ a different domain.

[jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)